# Proving that it is an equalizer

Tags: category-theory

Having given a category, a pair of parallel morphisms $f$ and $g$ and a morphism $e$, what is the simplest way to prove that $e$ is an equalizer of $f$ and $g$?

Can equalizers be defined purely equationally? If yes, how exactly?

Comment: All limits can be defined purely equationally. This is a good exercise in checking your understanding.

Comment: At least split equalizers http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+equalizer can be defined equationally. Arbitrary equalizers not, since they don't have to be preserved by functors. Or what do you mean by "purely equationally"?